# Ubuntu wlan drivers installation. (NETWJORK W522U and ZyXEL AWD 2205) ubuntu 10.04

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 10.04, usb

At beginning I must to say I'm sorry for my bad English.

I have both of the wlan adapters and I tried to install drivers but they are not doing anything. There are what I had do:

1. I bought Zyxel NWD2205 usb wlan adapter. My Ubuntu does not found it but command lsusb did it.
2. So, I download the driver from realtech home page, and I installed in. It were work, I can go to internet and anything.
3. Driver does not work now.  I don't know when it stopped, and I doesn't had install Ubuntu before it.
4. I tried to install driver again. It freezes my Ubuntu. Mouse does not move, clock stops, keyboard does not do anything...
5. I buy NETWJORK W522U usb wlan adapter. It have a linux driver with it. I run
   it with command "sudo make" and it prints no error, but Ubuntu still don't find it.
6. I install ndikswrapper and I try it. Both windows drivers make error.
7. I write this message, hope it works.

Okay, I did all this, and My wlan still not working, my computer does not find the drivers.

Information about my computer:
2001, so over 10 years old, run windows xp before I installed Ubuntu
Fujitsu Siemens Computers: Scaleo 600

Information about wlan:
Modem is ZyXEL (I don't remember the model)
I have NETWJORK W522U and ZyXEL AWD 2205, both usb.
My Ubuntu is 10.04 LTS, with no support.

So can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or tell me what I need to buy to get working wlan in Ubuntu? Must I have install newer ubuntu (10.04 NOT SUPPORTED ANYMORE)

Thanks for the help average.

Comment: After `sudo make` you must use `sudo make install` to install the driver. For others provide us `lsusb` result not the model number. The question is off topic in this site as per [FAQ]. It says questions for EOL ubuntu are considered off topic. So better upgrade to a later version which does support many more hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, problem solved (about 6 months ago). I only installed Ubuntu 12.04, and it was working. It was too slow of cource, but with LXDE it is ok.